# Python: Calculate the average of datetime with milliseconds

Tags: python

How can I get the average of two datetimes containing milliseconds?

Say I have this:

```
s1 = '00:02:25'
s2 = '00:04:40'
FMT = '%M:%S:%f'

d1 = datetime.strptime(s1, FMT)
d2 = datetime.strptime(s2, FMT)
```

To my knowledge there is no unix millisecond method. Would the only solution be to convert the minutes and seconds to milliseconds separately, and then calculate the average on that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure what result you are looking for. Does this suffice?

```
import datetime as DT

s1 = '00:02:25'
s2 = '00:04:40'
FMT = '%M:%S:%f'

d1 = DT.datetime.strptime(s1, FMT)
d2 = DT.datetime.strptime(s2, FMT)

delta = (d2-d1)/2
mid = d1 + delta
print(mid)
```

yields

```
1900-01-01 00:00:03.325000
```

Comment: A comment for the original poster: it is meaningful to *subtract* dates (and obtain a time interval, i.e. a `datetime.timedelta` object) but not to *add* dates (as one would naively do in order to get a mean with the formula `(d1+d2)/2`); similarly, it is meaningful to add a time interval to a date. This is what is done in unutbu's answer.

Comment: That's exactly where I got confused @EOL. Thanks for the clarification.